# Magento | How to make shopping cart rule depend on Total price of order not subtotal

Tags: magento-1.9

Hot to make shopping cart rule depend on the total price of the order not subtotal of every item as this is the default of magento!

Comment: http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/magento-shopping-cart-promotion-grand-total/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this doc, it may help you :
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/shopping-cart-and-catalog-price-rules-in-magento/